# VelocityEngine - how to get it properly and cannot find .vm file

Tags: java, spring, velocity

```
@Service
public class EmailService{
    VelocityEngine velocityEngine;

    @Bean
    public VelocityEngine getVelocityEngine() throws VelocityException, IOException {
        VelocityEngineFactory factory = new VelocityEngineFactory();
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("resource.loader", "class");
        props.put("class.resource.loader.class", "org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.ClasspathResourceLoader");
        props.put("classpath.resource.loader.class", ClasspathResourceLoader.class.getName());
        factory.setVelocityProperties(props);
        return factory.createVelocityEngine();
    }
}
```

applicationContext.xml

```
<bean id="velocityEngine"
      class="org.springframework.ui.velocity.VelocityEngineFactoryBean">
    <property name="resourceLoaderPath" value="${velocity.resourceLoader.path}" />
</bean>
```

applicationContext.properties

```
velocity.resourceLoader.path=C:\\Users\\Dev\\Git\\MyProject\\resources\\WEB-INF\\velocity
```

> org.apache.velocity.exception.ResourceNotFoundException: Unable to find resource 'voucherSummary_mail.vm'

1. How do I get `VelocityEngine` without the `getVelocityEngine()` method?
2. How do I make `VelocityEngine` get the template file from the folder that I set in applicationContext?

Comment: I Believe you should use `FileResourceLoader` to get the path . like `webapp.resource.loader.path=WEB-INF/velocity`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Velocity, different template paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12669375/velocity-different-template-paths)