# Velocity template cannot be found in Windows 10

Tags: java, velocity

My laptop just got upgraded to windows 10 from windows 7, and a piece of code stopped working. A large application using velocity templates which used to work on windows 7 just fine now cannot find the template files.

The templates are kept at the path **WebContent\WEB-INF\config\templates** under the project directory. An EngineInitializer class is used to load them. The code for the class is as follows:

```
private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(EngineInitializer.class);

private static String RELATIVE_PATH_FOR_TEMPLATES = "/WEB-INF/config/templates";
    if(logger.isDebugEnabled())
        logger.debug("About to initialize the Velocity Engine");
    Properties p = new Properties();
    String absolutePath=new File(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("").getFile()).getParentFile().getParentFile().getPath();//this goes to webapps directory
    //configure the velocity logger to use the default logging
    p.put(RuntimeConstants.RUNTIME_LOG_LOGSYSTEM_CLASS,"org.apache.velocity.runtime.log.Log4JLogChute");
    p.put("runtime.log.logsystem.log4j.logger", "defaultLog");
    p.put("file.resource.loader.path", absolutePath + RELATIVE_PATH_FOR_TEMPLATES);
    p.put("file.resource.loader.cache", "true");
    p.put("file.resource.loader.modificationCheckInterval", "-1");
    p.put("parser.pool.size", "30");

    Velocity.init(p);
    if(logger.isInfoEnabled())
        logger.info("The velocity engine is now initialized..");
```

The following lines in the applicationBeans.xml file initializes the engine:

```
<!-- initialize the velocity engine before the listener thread starts -->
<bean id="engineInitializer" class="com.file.myprogram.template.processor.EngineInitializer"
    init-method="initializeEngine" />
```

At the beginning, the log is getting printed. Inside the individual classes, the templates are called using Velocity.getTemplate() method. This is now returning a *org.apache.velocity.exception.ResourceNotFoundException: Unable to find resource 'MediationZone.vm'* error. Nothing other than the underlying OS has been changed. This code runs fine on an RHEL server as a web app. Code has been downloaded from subversion and run on the windows 10 laptop using eclipse v4.9.

What is going wrong here?

Comment: As I said, this program is running fine in Windows 7 and RHEL, so if filename case was an issue, it would be an issue elsewhere as well. Nevertheless, yes, the filename case is accurate.

Comment: @AviBis FYI windows does not check case sensitive.so it must be some other issue.

Comment: That's what I said.

Comment: Is there anyone who can answer this question?

Comment: I still don't know why this happened. However, I removed the project and downloaded from SVN again, and it started working.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and nothing worked (`file:/` prefix variants, `C:` or `c:`).

Finally I tried it with some **relative path** (like used in the production environment) and voilà, it worked.

Figured out current run dir using `System.getProperty("user.dir")`:

```
vel.getTemplate( "foo/bar/some.vm", UTF_8.name() )
```

Comment: maybe it is related to the `RuntimeConstants.FILE_RESOURCE_LOADER_PATH` property: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12669531/1915920